# why if condition in jquery template executed multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-templates

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var attendees = { Name: "Hajan", Surname: "Selmani" };
              $("#attendeesTemplate").tmpl(attendees).appendTo("#attendeesList");
        });
        function test(a, b) {
            alert(a + " " + b);
            return 1;
        }
    </script>
<script id="attendeesTemplate" type="text/html">
        <li>
        {{if test(1,2)==1}}
            ${Name} ${Surname}
        {{/if}}        
        </li>
    </script>
```

Why is the if condition in the jquery template executed 4 times?

Comment: the templating engine can do what it needs to

Comment: could you specify your template engine, as @DanielA.White wrote it might be a template-specific issue

Comment: If it Handlebars as I guess then may be you miss `#` in `if` - `{{#if test(1,2)==1}}`

Comment: {{if test(1,2)}}
            ${Name} ${Surname}
        {{/if}}  

this if executed one time only.why?

Comment: how fix it in jquery.tmpl.js templating engine @АлексейОвчинников

Comment: how fix it in jquery.tmpl.js templating engine @DanielA.White

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want it recomputed? the template engine might have a reason for reevaluating it.

Comment: if i use global value in the function (example: c++ or c--) @DanielA.White